# How can i see the output of the Visual Studio if i have to terminate the console?

Tags: c, visual-studio, console-application

I have to count the digits, white spaces and other characters in C using Visual Studio 2013. So, i input something and then i have to recive the output. The problem is that i don't know how to exit the 'inputting' mode. All i can do is input text from keyboard or close the console.

Notes:

- I am using Console Application, i've tried Windows Application but no luck
- I've tried with and without Debug.
- In Eclipse this exact code is working
- I've tried using Ctrl+Z

Eclipse example:

He has 10 apples

digits = 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 , white space = 4, other= 11

```
main(){

int c, i, nwhite, nother;
int ndigit[10];

nwhite = nother = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    ndigit[i] = 0;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        ++ndigit[c - '0'];
    else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
        ++nwhite;
    else
        ++nother;

printf("digits = ");
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    printf("%d ", ndigit[i]);

printf(", white space = %d, other= %d", nwhite, nother);
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Press CTRL+Z. It sends an `EOF` signal in the `stdin`

Comment: The title of the question and the details are different.  In the title you're asking: "How can i see the output of the Visual Studio if i have to terminate the console?" and in the description you're asking: "The problem is that i don't know how to exit the 'inputting' mode.".  To view output window in Visual Studio, you can click on View->Output (or CTRL+ALT+O), but if you terminate your console application, you won't view anything in the output window

Comment: i've used the term "terminate" in my question because that is how the process of exiting the console in Eclipse is named.

Answer (score 2):

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
```

with that, the only way you can stop input is to press Ctrl + Z and hit the Enter.

Comment: I forgot to mention that i've tried using Ctrl+Z but all that it did was to display in my console something like " ^Z "

Comment: @user3569896, Press Enter after Ctrl + Z. `^Z` is exactly what you should expect when you hit Ctrl + Z